# How can I give Google Maps API landscape a background image instead of a background color?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am experimenting with Google Maps API for the first time.

I have got as far as positioning and zooming the map, removing features and removing certain UI Controls.

I have also managed to give the landscape a background color.

```
  {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ff0000"
      }
    ]
  }
```

But I would like to give the landscape a **background image**, rather than a background color.

I can either do this directly using something like:

```
  {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "background-image": "/my-image.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
```

or else give `#map` a `background-image` using CSS and give the landscape background colour an opacity of `0` using alpha channel (either `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` or else `hsla`) to allow the `background-image` to show through.

But so far, I have been unable to get either of these approaches to work - the `"color"` key only seems to take a hex value. (Really?)

How can I give the landscape a **background image** instead of a background color?

Comment: Is the background image supposed to be fixed or to move along with the map?

Comment: The background will consistently cover one part of the map. Imagine a rectangular-framed map showing the United Kingdom. At the initial zoom level, a little of France and Belgium are visible in the bottom right corner and all of the Republic of Ireland is visible. The photo background is to cover exactly the United Kingdom (ie. including Northern Ireland, but excluding the Isle of Man).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the term for what I was looking for is not **Custom Overlay**, but **Ground Overlay**.

This (more straightforward) overlay solution is rather simpler.

To create a **Ground Overlay** there are only **2 steps**:

## Step 1

Declare variables for the image you wish to use and the latitude and longitude co-ordinates for both the top-right and bottom left corners of your image:

```
var imageSrc = '/my-image.png';
var imageNortheastCorner = new google.maps.LatLng(58.70303006647019, 2.439521484375);
var imageSouthwestCorner = new google.maps.LatLng(49.99166659140519, -8.402314453125);
```

## Step 2

Apply the declared variables to create both the *image bounds* and the *overlay* and then add the overlay to the map:

```
var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(imageSouthwestCorner, imageNortheastCorner);

myOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(imageSrc, imageBounds);

myOverlay.setMap(map);
```

That's all that is needed.

---

Special thanks to this page (quite far down the search results) which showed how simple the process is:

http://maps.zemplate.com/customizing-maps/add-an-image-overlay-to-a-google-map

Comment: Well the whole point of using a custom map type with custom tiles (which, I suppose, is what you refer to by *the verbose code in the docs*) is that you can serve tiles for different zoom levels... And btw there is [an example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/groundoverlays) in the docs that explains exactly what you described here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by [adding a custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple). Click the link to see a working example.

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: {lat: 62.323907, lng: -150.109291},
      mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
        new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608));

    // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
    var srcImage = 'url_of_your_image';

    // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
    // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
    overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this already. I'll adopt this approach if there is nothing better, but it seems a painfully difficult way to get all of the land to have a photographic background, but none of the sea.

Comment: Have you tried the example on this page [Showing/Hiding overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow).

Answer (score 0):

you can not give a background image, as stated here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference

color (an RGB hex string of format #RRGGBB) sets the color of the feature.

and there is no feature for images, my suggestion would be to start a Feature Request in the issue tracker suggesting to add this feature to the JSON style object. (https://issuetracker.google.com)