# How to hide Google Map but remains my location shown including the markers?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I followed the documentation of [Google Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) to implement it.

But instead of showing the Map, I want it invisible, but remains my location shown into where it should it be including the markers.

can it be done? how?

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39220091/is-it-possible-to-hide-map-but-show-only-markers-android-google-maps) but it's been a year, I'm thinking maybe there's already solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can not since is against Google policy:

> No use of Content without a Google map. Unless the Maps APIs Documentation expressly permits you to do so, you will not use the Content in a Maps API Implementation without a corresponding Google map. For example, you may display Street View imagery without a corresponding Google map because the Maps APIs Documentation expressly permits this use.
>
> No use of Content with a non-Google map. You must not use the Content in a Maps API Implementation that contains a non-Google map.

check this to make sure if your app does no break any Google terms https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions

Comment: Awts. Though I can use a custom image.

Comment: you can overlay an image on top, but I believe that it needs to be on top of the Google maps, maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665357/how-can-i-give-google-maps-api-landscape-a-background-image-instead-of-a-backgro/48666495#48666495

Answer (score 0):

You can use [styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) to hide whatever map feature you like.

Here is an example map, with everything hidden and a fill color applied on all geometry to have an uniform background worldwide.

```js
function initialize() {

  var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(40.744656, -74.005966);
  var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243685);
  var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
  var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();

  var markers = [];

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.392303, -86.931067);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [{
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#fff050"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }
    ],
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  // Create some markers
  for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(), southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });

    markers.push(marker);
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Using `disableDefaultUI: true` will also remove all the map controls. The logo and text on the bottom right you have to keep for legal aspects.

[This tool](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) can help you achieve the result you like.

All this is documented and perfectly legal.

**Edit:** This example uses the Javascript API (as you tagged your question with google-maps-api-3) but you can achieve the same on Android, see [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/style-reference).